# Replacing multiple value within cell in dataframe - Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm searching for solution how to replace several strings within one cell inside of data frame in Python-Pandas.

Each column has unique elements to be replaced based on legend that is already defined.

I've already find solution how to replace values within column, but result that I get replace only one string at time, and removing other. For example cell value: AA, BB, CC
legend: AA - Level 1, BB - Level 2, CC - Level 3, DD - Level 4
result: Level 1.

```py
Data set:
Field Name | Category 1 | Category 2
Test1        AA BB CC      LD DD
Test2        BB CC         DD
Test3        AA            LD
Test4        AA BB DD      LD DD

Legend:
AA - Level 1, BB - Level 2, CC - Level 3, DD - Level 4
LD - High, DD - Low
```

I expect result to be combined with one cell, for example: Level 1; Level 2 while cell value was AA, BB

Comment: What kind of data structure does your `legend` have? Is that a dictionary?

Comment: Create dictionary and then `replace`

Comment: @jezrael, this would not work for this case since he has multiple values in one cell

Comment: yes legend can be dictionary it simple match string to value: AA - Level 1

Comment: Which pandas version are you on? `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: My version is 0.23.4

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
d = {'AA':'Level 1','BB':'Level 2','CC':'Level 3','DD':'Level 4','LD': 'High', 'DD' :'Low'}

regex = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(regex, lambda x: d[x.group()], regex=True))

print (df)

  Field Name               Category 1 Category 2
0      Test1  Level 1 Level 2 Level 3   High Low
1      Test2          Level 2 Level 3        Low
2      Test3                  Level 1       High
3      Test4      Level 1 Level 2 Low   High Low
```

If need apply solution only for one column:

```
df['Category 1'] = df['Category 1'].str.replace(regex, lambda x: d[x.group()], regex=True)
```

Comment: Nice one, what does `d[x.group()]` do in this case? +1

Comment: Thank you! I will check this very shortly and come back with feedback

Comment: @Erfan - It is regex with callback :)

Comment: Once I add code as described below (add reference to the specify column in my data set) it is throwing an error as follow:

 File "<ipython-input-17-5e5ed74417ef>", line 4
    df.['Data Class'] = df.['Data Class'].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(regex, lambda x: d[x.group()])
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Change `df.['Data Class']`  to `df['Data Class']`

Comment: Done: Now it is throwing this:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @mikemorrison - Answer was modify with solution for one column, tested with None and `NaN` and working nice for me.

Comment: I excluded all None values and it is returning:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @mikemorrison - there is no typo?

Comment: @mikemorrison - Can you change data for better data sample for see your problem?

Comment: I've checked and my data is identified not as string, but as object. Does it relevant for solution?